# Summing the inventory values across different warehouse locations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wish to SUM the total value of the Part Numbers(ITEMID) across their respective locations(SITEID).

I've managed to build a view displaying our Part Numbers(ITEMID) and their configuration(CONFIGID), together with their inventory quantities in different warehouse locations.

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.INVENTSUM.ITEMID,
dbo.INVENTDIM.CONFIGID, SUM(dbo.INVENTSUM.AVAILPHYSICAL) AS TOH,
dbo.INVENTDIM.INVENTSITEID

FROM dbo.INVENTSUM INNER JOIN
dbo.INVENTDIM ON dbo.INVENTSUM.INVENTDIMID =
dbo.INVENTDIM.INVENTDIMID

GROUP BY dbo.INVENTSUM.ITEMID, dbo.INVENTDIM.INVENTSITEID,
dbo.INVENTDIM.CONFIGID

HAVING (dbo.INVENTSUM.ITEMID LIKE N'36-2%') AND
(dbo.INVENTDIM.CONFIGID
= N'776')

ORDER BY dbo.INVENTSUM.ITEMID
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
ITEM ID CONFIGID  AVAILPHYSICAL         SITEID
36-2001   776   104.0000000000000000    PKR
36-2001   776   3.0000000000000000      USS002
36-2001   776   0.0000000000000000      CANS001
```

I'm looking for how to output the following:

```
ITEM ID   CONFIGID  AVAILPHYSICAL
36-2001     776          107
```

I understand that I shouldn't create another view to reference this one? Because I experimented with doing that and managed to achieve the desired output.

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT PARTNO, CONFIG, SUM(QTY) AS Expr1
FROM dbo._vw_Advance_FDO_Data
GROUP BY PARTNO, CONFIG
ORDER BY PARTNO
```

I'm given:

```
PARTNO   CONFIG   QTY
36-2001    776    358.0000000000000000
36-200106  776    12.0000000000000000
36-2006    776    81.0000000000000000
36-2006B   776    40.0000000000000000
```

With what I learned about nested views, I altered the first view with the suggested changes:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.INVENTSUM.ITEMID AS PARTNO,
dbo.INVENTDIM.CONFIGID AS CONFIG, SUM(dbo.INVENTSUM.AVAILPHYSICAL) AS QTY

FROM dbo.INVENTSUM INNER JOIN
dbo.INVENTDIM ON dbo.INVENTSUM.INVENTDIMID = dbo.INVENTDIM.INVENTDIMID

GROUP BY dbo.INVENTSUM.ITEMID, dbo.INVENTDIM.CONFIGID

HAVING (dbo.INVENTSUM.ITEMID LIKE N'36-2%') AND (dbo.INVENTDIM.CONFIGID =
N'776')
ORDER BY PARTNO
```

It appears this gives me the desired output!

```
PARTNO     CONFIG     QTY
36-2001      776     358.0000000000000000
36-200106    776     12.0000000000000000
```

Comment: Remove dbo.INVENTDIM.INVENTSITEID from the group by. But you need to start using aliases. 3 and 4 part column names in the select list has been deprecated. And it is really painful to read.

Comment: and also remove it from the SELECT list.

Comment: Don't do that!!!! Nested views are the spawn of satan. They will crush your server in ways you can't even imagine. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven And don't get fooled into thinking using top 100 percent with an order by in a view means the view will be ordered like that.....it won't....but sometimes it will. That is a big fallacy. https://web.archive.org/web/20160808070425/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/

Comment: Ok, so don't use another view to reference the one I created above? In other words, this *is* a "nested view" yes?

Comment: If you have a view that selects from a view you have a timebomb on your hands. The performance will be fine for awhile and suddenly it will slow down by absurd amounts. I am talking things like suddenly it will be 1000% slower than it was yesterday. Read the article by Grant I posted above. Besides you don't need all that. See the query I posted in an answer. It addresses your query with no need for other views or anything. Just a simple select statement.

Comment: I will work to implement those changes you suggest as well as read those materials. Thank you!!!

Comment: Any idea how I might be able to remove the decimals from the QTY values? I'm not sure how to implement a CAST statement...

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you query would look like using aliases. It is a ton easier to read and WAY less to type. I also moved your HAVING to the WHERE clause. Where is used to filter rows, having is used to filter groups.

```
SELECT i.ITEMID
    , id.CONFIGID
    , SUM(i.AVAILPHYSICAL) AS TOH
FROM dbo.INVENTSUM i
INNER JOIN dbo.INVENTDIM id ON i.INVENTDIMID = id.INVENTDIMID
WHERE i.ITEMID LIKE N'36-2%'
    AND id.CONFIGID = N'776'
GROUP BY i.ITEMID
    , id.CONFIGID
ORDER BY i.ITEMID
```

Comment: Any idea how I might be able to remove the decimals from the QTY values?

Comment: Sure just convert it to int.